# How to detect if Line2D is visible on screen in Godot?

Tags: godot

I know we can use `VisibleOnScreenEnabler2D` for other nodes like `Area2D`. However, it doesn't seem to work with `Line2D`. How can I achieve the same functionality as `VisibleOnScreenEnabler2D` for `Line2D`?